# time limit exceeded error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am running code on leetcode with the question:

Given an array of integers, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number.

The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target, where index1 must be less than index2. Please note that your returned answers (both index1 and index2) are not zero-based.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.

Input: numbers={2, 7, 11, 15}, target=9
Output: index1=1, index2=2

My answer is very straightforward:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &numbers, int target) {
        vector<int> result;

        for(int i=0;i<numbers.size()-1;i++){
          for(int j=1+i;j<numbers.size();j++){
             if (numbers[i]+numbers[j]==target)
                 { result.push_back(i+1);
                   result.push_back(j+1);
                   return result;}
          }
        } 
        return result;
    }
};
```

By using double loops, its complexity should be (O**2). However, I got the error like "Running time limit exceeded". What is the problem please?

PS: I know the method using hash map can fasten it. I am just confused with the error. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe they want you to use the faster solution?

Comment: The problem most probably is that there is test data, much, much bigger, to test more performance solution and it's failing.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of having a class for this problem.  Put the code in the `main()` function or another function.  The C++ language doesn't require everything to be in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your program runs too long and was terminated.